# Redirecting page (mod rewrite) not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am having this in my .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC] 
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profiles.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's working fine om my computer, but om my webserver it fails.

It does however redirect to the profiles.php page, but I can't retrieve the value behind the dash with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Does this mean mod_rewrite is not active or is something else wrong?

Comment: If mod_rewrite wasn’t available, you would get an internal server error by using these directives. It’s more likely something in the server/php config that doesn’t pass the PATH_INFO to PHP scripts. Take a look into the whole $_SERVER array, if you find the value somewhere else, f.e. in REQUEST_URI.

Comment: OK, added it as an answer. Could you also say how exactly it solved your problem, resp. what you changed in your config/script? That might help other people as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mod_rewrite wasn’t available, you would get an internal server error by using these directives. It’s more likely something in the server/php config that doesn’t pass the PATH_INFO to PHP scripts.

Take a look into the whole $_SERVER array, if you find the value somewhere else, f.e. in REQUEST_URI. (There you’re likely to find to find the whole path, like `/profiles.php/path_info_data_here`, so you would have to strip the first part.)